# Using a JSON file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm looking to use a JSON file in a Node.js project, but it doesn't seem to be working-

```
var JsonPath = '../../folderOfjsonFiles';
var JsonFile = JsonPath + 'test.json';

var parseThis = JSON.parse(JsonFile);
console.dir(parseThis);
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong? Running this yields this error:

```
    "test1": {
        ^
   uncaught: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Module._compile (module.js:399:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:410:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
    at require (module.js:348:19)
```

Where test1 is the first JSON object in my file.

This is my JSON file-

```
{
    "test1": {
        "testname": "alpha",
        "password": "password"
    }
}
```

Even before the JSON parsing, how do I read from a file that I will store locally on the server-side? I feel like I'm overcomplicating this.

Comment: Post your "JSON" file.  Or at least the first few lines.

Comment: So the above file is throwing the SyntaxError(http://www.jsonlint.com/) bc its valid JSON ?

Answer (score 4):

A JSON object has to be included in `{}` or `[]` at top level, so you cant do

```
"test1": {...},
"test2": {...}
```

Use

```
{
  "test1": {...},
  "test2": {...}
}
```

instead.

Comment: It's already in the right format, I believe-

{
 "test1": {
  "testname": alpha,
  "password": password
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

I store my Express server config in a file and read it like this:

`var fs = require('fs');`
`var path = require('path');`
`var conf = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './config.json'), 'utf8');`