# Using php preg_replace to parse out target double quotes in JSON string

Tags: php, json, preg-replace, double-quotes

I've been beating my head on this one, and can't figure out a regexp to accomplish the following:

Input string (this is JSON data surrounded by lots of other JSON):

```
$string=..."natural_order":"12"...
```

where 12 could also be a decimal like "1.2", or could be larger like 1288 or 1.288.

Desired string:

```
..."natural_order":12...
```

Using php preg_replace, so far I've gotten:

```
preg_replace('/[^natural_order:]+"/', '', $string);
```

but only returns:

```
"12"
```

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: `preg_replace` is for modifying the target string. To extract something you would need `preg_match`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762739/how-can-i-parse-this-json-data/5762810#5762810

Answer (score 2):

Instead of tricky regexen, I'd suggest something along these lines:

```
$array = json_decode($string, true);
array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$value, $key) {
    if ($key == 'natural_order') {
        $value = strpos($value, '.') ? (float)$value : (int)$value;
    }
});
$string = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing I didn't want to write out... ;-)

Comment: @Over I think this was faster to write out than trying to mind bend the right regex... ;)

Comment: Of note, anonymous functions (AKA closures) require PHP 5.3 or newer.  But that can be rewritten using the old-style callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions.  The first, which I won't bother writing out, would be to decode the JSON using `json_decode`, correct the values by parsing them into ints, and re-encoding the string.

The second is to continue down your path.  However, JSON is a fairly complicated string, and can't be reliably parsed using just a regex.  If you are confident that the pattern `"natural_order":"value"` won't show up somewhere else, you could try this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/"natural_order"\s*\:\s*"([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)"/', '"natural_order":$1', $string);
```

This should match any encapsulated key, followed by a colon, followed by an encapsulated valid floating point number.  There's also escapes in case there are spaces around the colon.

Comment: I updated my example.  I had an extra ` \ ` hiding in the replacement string.